# Can't boot Ubuntu or Windows (dual boot) after BIOS update

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, bios, grub-efi, fdisk

I have dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 on HP Pavilion. When I tried update BIOS (update downloaded from official HP website). After that I couldn't boot neither Ubuntu or Windows so I tried to use Ubuntu live USB to try erase both Ubuntu and Windows partitions using GParted and fdisk but couldn't erase them. Every time I tried I got message like there is I/O error so GParted or fdisk couldn't do anything. I also tried to install Ubuntu again but that also failed.

> Edit: here are some screenshots

1. This is from GParted
   [GParted_start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrQaE.png)
   [GParted_partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt325.png)
   [Info_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmN02.png)
   [Info_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ud45.png)
2. This is from fdisk - tried to modify /dev/nvme0n1p2
   [fdisk_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWehH.png)
3. This is message from Boot Repair tool
   [Boot Repair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Opr.png)

Comment: I/O errors almost always mean a faulty drive.

Comment: Can you post here some screenshots (taken by e.g. mobile) when these issues occurs? Without, we are not able to help you most probably... Are your hard drives recognized by BIOS (or most probably by UEFI) ? Useful can be even screenshot from Ubuntu installer on point when you setting you partition(s) which will be used for Ubuntu installation. Have you let Ubuntu to do partition stuff itself or you selected that you would like to do partition stuff by yourself?

Comment: I added a few screenshots in my post

Comment: "Have you let Ubuntu to do partition stuff itself or you selected that you would like to do partition stuff by yourself?" - I've set partitions manually while installing Ubuntu before, but this time Ubuntu install process can't go any further than step where asks me whether I want normal installation or minimal